# Why is the hair is only on one side?

Tags: particles, hair

I've just started learning blender and I don't know how to change the particle position. I wanna move the hair to the other side. How do I do it?[image]

Comment: Hello :). By default, hair particles direction depends on face normals. You could simply go Mesh > Normals > Flip.

Comment: or just rotate the plane 180 on x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This delves into the concept of normals, and mathematical planes. My short answer is to extrude the plane a bit, then recalculate all the normals in the Mesh menu (make sure to select everything first). This will turn the plane from a two dimensional area into a three-dimensional object, and will allow it to emit hair from both sides.

If you don’t want the plane to be solid at all, I recommend changing how the hair is emitted to not use normals.

Answer (score 1):

To apply hair particle to all sides, use normal hair particle setting then extrude plane a bit. Or you dan use solidify modified then go to hair particles setting > source> check "Use Modifier stack"